# change asset browser material thumbnail

Tags: interface

Under Properties>Materials>Preview you can change the thumbnail example type
Is there a way to change the asset browser's material thumbnail type to your own model?

[image]

Comment: You can load a custom preview but you have to render it to a file on your system and load it manually for each material though.

Comment: Thanks, what folder does the image go into ?

Comment: It can be any image you have on your system

Comment: Yes, I understand an image can replace the AB standard thumbnail. My question is Where does that image go within the Blender folder? thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it doesnt. The only thing that's stored is the path link to the image file, which is dynamically fetched whenever you open this particular asset library to display it